# How to verify that were not invocation of methods of the mock object? Mockito

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito

How to verify that there were no invocations of methods of the mock object?

I want something like that:

```
Mockito.assertNoOneMethodWasCalled(myMockObject);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check that no interaction happened at all:

```
verifyZeroInteractions(Object... mocks)
```

If you want to check that no interactions happened after certain calls:

```
verifyNoMoreInteractions(Object... mocks)
```

If you want to verify single method:

```
verify(mock, never()).methodCall();
verify(mock, times(0)).methodCall();
```